Find distinct values in field of array of strings using Prisma
I am new to Prisma. I have a Postgres data set where the entries include a field named genres that is an array of strings. I want to call to the database using prisma and return an array of distinct genres. What I want to avoid is treating an array of genres as a distinct value. Example below.
Currently I am calling
const genres = await db.track.findMany({
   distinct: ['genres'],
   select: { genres: true }
});

which is returning
[
   { genres: [ 'house' ] },
   { genres: [ 'techno' ] },
   { genres: [ 'house', 'techno' ] },
]

Ideally I would like to be getting
[ 'house', 'techno' ]

This doesn't seem to be a scenario natively supported by Prisma. However, since for distinct Prisma internally uses a SELECT and then does in-memory processing (source: the docs), I wouldn't worry about the lack of support.
I would implement my own in-memory distinct filtering:
const uniqueGenres = new Set(values.flatMap(({ genres }) => genres));
console.log(uniqueGenres)
// ^ Set { 0: 'house', 1: 'techno' }

// Option 1: Spread into an array
const spreadIntoArray = [...uniqueGenres];
console.log(spreadIntoArray)
// ^ [ 'house', 'techno' ]

// Option 2: Use Array.from
const arrayFromSet = Array.from(uniqueGenres);
console.log(arrayFromSet);
// ^ [ 'house', 'techno' ]

